# Bind multiple sets of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a survey generator, that can have several sets of checkboxes. I was planning to generate them so they have names like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="5_5_c" name="[0].isChecked"/>
```

This way I can accept a model like: List where CheckTypeQuestion has a List amongst other things.

The problem I have, is that my approach would not differentiate checkboxes from different questions. It would at best, collect them all in one big list.

What is the best way of doing this?
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How I have done this in the past is on the controller do a

```
var List = Request.Form["Name"].ToString();
```

which will have a list of all of the checkboxes that were checked with that matching name.  Hopefully this helps